# Cannot compile tabu

Tags: tables, xetex, tabu

I have been trying to compile the following tabu environment with xelatex, but to no avail:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}




\begin{document}
\taburowcolors 10{green!25 .. yellow!80}
\begin{tabu}{X[-1]X}
%\everyrow{\midrule}
\repeatcell 2{
rows=10,
text/col1=Teste,
text/col2={Row number
       \row$=$\thetaburow},
}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

It generates an error: "undefined control sequence \end{tabu}."

Comment: Could you please use one of the other table packages? "Using tabu is taboo", as some one put it, mildly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example does not produce the error that you state. It produces:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text>  \repeatcell
```

`\repeatcell` isn't defined by `tabu` and the `text/col1=Teste,` syntax looks more `tikz/pgf` than than `tabu`.

adding

```
 \usepackage{makecell,interfaces-makecell}
```

fixes things.

Comment: It's a copy from the tabu documentation -- I thought it just worked.

Comment: @Joseph sorry I don't know what I did before: the example is in the tabu doc (it doesn't work though without some unspecified additional package)

Comment: @Joseph see updated answer with working code.

Comment: Great, it works fine now.